# SmoothStateJS with Custom Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, smoothstate.js

I know this question has been asked a few times before, but looking through the answers I still can't figure out how to fix the issue, Would someone be able to help?

My map works when I refresh the page, but when I navigate to it from any other page the map doesn't load, as smoothState doesn't reload the page.

I've got the rest of my js working, it's just the maps that won't load unless I refresh the page.

I've read almost all of the posts on github regarding this and a few on stackoverflow, but I keep going round in circles and not getting anyway.

My js for `smoothState` and google maps

No grey spaces or coloured boxes etc, and no errors in console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $body = $('body'),
    $main = $('#main'),
    $site = $('html, body'),
    transition = 'fade',
    smoothState;

  smoothState = $main.smoothState({
    onBefore: function($anchor, $container) {
      var current = $('[data-viewport]').first().data('viewport'),
        target = $anchor.data('target');
      current = current ? current : 0;
      target = target ? target : 0;
      if (current === target) {
        transition = 'fade';
      } else if (current < target) {
        transition = 'moveright';
      } else {
        transition = 'moveleft';
      }
    },
    onStart: {
      duration: 400,
      render: function(url, $container) {
        $main.attr('data-transition', transition);
        $main.addClass('is-exiting');
        $site.animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        });
      }
    },
    onReady: {
      duration: 0,
      render: function($container, $newContent) {
        $container.html($newContent);
        $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
      }
    },
    onAfter: function($container) {
      $container.onPageLoad();
    },
  }).data('smoothState');
});

function init_map() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    backgroundColor: "#212121",

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4864171, -2.2338110000000597),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    styles: [{
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#ccc'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'administrative.locality',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          visibility: 'none'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          visibility: 'none'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#263c3f'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          visibility: 'none'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#38414e'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#212a37'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#9ca5b3'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#ccc'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#1f2835'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#ccc'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#2f3948'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#ccc'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#515c6d'
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      }
    ]
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng()
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(
    marker, 'click',
    function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  );
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

Comment: `it's just the maps that won't load unless I refresh the page` How it looks? an empty grey rectangle? Or nothing? What the chance that you will create a **working** demo snippet which reproduce the problem?

Comment: No Grey spaces, and no errors in the console. Working on setting up a demo now will have a link in 5-10 mins.

Comment: Link to temp staging site: http://staging.johnswiftproperty.co.uk

Comment: Taking a look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when the other page than **contact** is loaded the `#gmap_canvas` is not exist yet. You can see it if you will pause on this line:

[image]

So the solution is to init the map only when this `div` is exist and the map not yet initialised.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $body = $('body'),
    $main = $('#main'),
    $site = $('html, body'),
    transition = 'fade',
    smoothState,
    // 1. declare this variable to know if the map is initialised
    initialisedMap = false;

  smoothState = $main.smoothState({
    //...
    onReady: {
      duration: 0,
      render: function($container, $newContent) {
        $container.html($newContent);
        $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
        // 2. call init_map() 
        init_map();
      }
    }
  });
});

function initMap() {
  // 3. if the map container is not exist do nothing
  if (!document.querySelector('#gmap_canvas')) {
    return;
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and for helping! It initialises for the first time I click on contact , but once i Click to another page and go back to contact it goes again. I've updated the demo site with this

Comment: Ok. Probably you need to init the map anytime the contact page is loaded. I updated my answer: run the `init_map` in each page change. in the `initMap` function check if the map's contains is exist. If not, do nothing. Let me know if it's working..

Comment: Yes that is all working now, Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Sure :) Good luck!